# Read multiple checkbox values into a email using mail()

Tags: php, html, email

I created a form and one field is a check box that asks for availability. My PHP script currently only emails the last selected value. Is there a way to email all selected values? I tried using implode and writing a for each loop, but was unable to get either to work.

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <p class="careerText">Schedule Availability. Please check all that apply</p>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="availability[]" value="Monday" id="Monday" required class="checkBox checkmark">
                                <label for="Monday" class="txt">Monday</label>
                                
                                <input type="checkbox" name="availability[]" value="Tuesday" id="Tuesday" required class="checkBox checkmark">
                                <label for="Tuesday" class="txt">Tuesday</label>
                                
                                <input type="checkbox" name="availability[]" value="Wednesday" id="Wednesday" required class="checkBox checkmark"> 
                                <label for="Wednesday" class="txt">Wednesday</label>
                                
                                <input type="checkbox" name="availability[]" value="Thursday" id="Thursday" required class="checkBox checkmark">
                                <label for="Thursday" class="txt">Thursday</label>
                                
                                <input type="checkbox" name="availability[]" value="Friday" id="Friday" required class="checkBox checkmark">
                                <label for="Friday" class="txt">Friday</label>
                                
                                <input type="checkbox" name="availability[]" value="Saturday" id="Saturday" required class="checkBox checkmark">
                                <label for="Saturday" class="txt">Saturday</label>
                                
                                <input type="checkbox" name="availability[]" value="Sunday" id="Sunday" required class="checkBox checkmark">
                                <label for="Sunday" class="txt">Sunday</label> 
                            </div>
```

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php

// Define some constants
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "test" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "test" );


// Read the form values
$success = false;
$firstName = $_POST['fname'];
$lastName =  $_POST['lname'];
$senderEmail =  $_POST['email'];
$senderPhone = isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\s\S\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['phone'] ) : "";
$certification = $_POST['certification'];
$availability = $_POST['availability'];
$shift = $_POST['shift_availability'];

//$availability = isset( $_POST['availability']) ? implode(', ', $_POST['availability']) : 'no availability selected';
//$shift = isset($_POST['shift']) ? implode(', ', $_POST['shift']) : 'no shifts selected';




// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $firstName && $lastName && $senderEmail && $senderPhone && $certification && $availability && $shift) {
  
  
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
    
  $headers = $firstName. " " . $lastName .  "Applied to Soulful Hands Home Care: " . "";
    
  $msgBody = "First Name: ". $firstName . "\n" . "Last Name: " . $lastName. "\n" . "Email: ". $senderEmail . "\n" . "Phone: ". $senderPhone . "\n" . "Certification: " . $certification . "\n" . "Availability: " . $availability . "\n" .  "Shift Availability: " . $shift . "";
  $success = mail( $recipient, $headers, $msgBody );
  

  //Set Location After Successsfull Submission
  header('Location: index.html?message=Successful');
}

else{
    //Set Location After Unsuccesssfull Submission
    header('Location: index.html?message=Failed');  
}


?>
```

Comment: can you show us what exactly is being posted in your email?

Comment: Please format your code and take care of guidelines : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

All of your checkboxes have the same name(availability[]). it is being treated as an array of the same input. it does not matter if you selected one or all. If you need to check for all the boxes separately, then you should have different names for them. Or use a string made from implode.

```
if ($_POST['availability']){
            $mfs_arr= $_POST['availability'];
            $str = implode (", ", $mfs_arr);
        }
```

I have tested this in my own environment and it is working properly. The output is: "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday". If you still can not get the input, it might be due to another part of your code.